# Origin of "scumbag"

Tags: etymology

A phrase I sometimes hear from one of my colleagues is *scumbag* or *scumbags*:

- Where does this phrase come from?
- How old is it?
- Is its usage still a common occurrence?

Comment: I think the popularity of "scumbag" has waned along with the Dirty Harry films, but it is still in use, and people would certainly be properly insulted if you called them that.  I'm going to start using it again myself, now that you've mentioned it.

Comment: Look what you've done!

Comment: @ThirdIdiot @Kit is yet another "convert". Whomever I mention this phrase to seems to adopt it!

Comment: Haha! The Phenomenon of the Treffynnon influence.

Comment: I am an avid user of the word. I used to own a shirt that just said "Scumbag" - after seeing this page, I do not believe I would have made that purchase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **scumbag** 
>   "condom," by 1967, slang, from *scum* + *bag*. Meaning "despicable person" is attested by 1971.

<sup>*[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=scumbag&searchmode=none)*</sup>

I found a condom reference back to 1939 in this [snippet](http://books.google.com/books?ei=M3jnTcaXM-Xq0QHXrNCgCw&ct=result&sqi=2&id=rsYVAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22scumbag%22%20OR%20%22scum%20bag%22&q=scum%20bag#search_anchor) from the *American Journal of Orthopsychiatry*, Volume 9. The date seems [accurate](http://books.google.com/books?ei=M3jnTcaXM-Xq0QHXrNCgCw&ct=result&sqi=2&id=rsYVAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22scumbag%22%20OR%20%22scum%20bag%22&q=1939#search_anchor):

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=rsYVAAAAIAAJ&q=%22scumbag%22+OR+%22scum+bag%22&dq=%22scumbag%22+OR+%22scum+bag%22&hl=en&ei=rXbnTdraLKLm0QGGnNX2Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBA]

And I found this figurative use of the phrase from Chandler Brossard's [1953](http://www.flickr.com/photos/29873672@N02/3383757924/) *The Bold Saboteurs*:

> What a scum bag of a world it was, what a miserable rat's life. I was getting so depressed I was forgetting the money in my pocket. In the early evening we all broke up. I told the fellows I might see them later at Sinbad's Bar

(See @Kit's comment above for current usage.)

Comment: So, as an insult, it is the male version of "douchebag"???

Comment: @Callithumpian: The 1939 snippet image is now broken and I don't see it at Google Books to upload via imgur.

Comment: @Hugo: What should I do, disable the links?

Comment: @Callithumpian: Strange, the image in the question is shown now. Must have been a temporary error. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5):

I found an earlier reference for *scum-bag* as a straining bag used when refining sugar, described in [1819](http://books.google.com/books?id=02EIAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA2-PT364&dq=%22scum%20bag%22&hl=en&ei=nRqtTsyCJOqQ4gTQia3WDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=scum%20bag&f=false)'s *The Cyclopædia;: or, Universal Dictionary of Arts, Sciences, and Literature*, Volume 34 by Abraham Rees:

> Having kept it simmering for several hours, and having provided a cooler or receiver, over which is placed a strong wooden frame, and upon this a basket, to which a coarse bag, called the *scum-bag*, is fitted, he pours the contents of his pan into this basket and bag; and then the mouth of the bag is drawn up, and well twisted together, and a strong board, called a *scum-board*, is laid upon the bags, with several weights upon the board, to press down the scum.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scum) notes *scum* is early 14th century from foam or froth and:

> Sense deteriorated from "thin layer atop liquid" to "film of dirt," then just "dirt." Meaning "lowest class of humanity" is 1580s

Comment: And if scum is dirty, the bag you collect it and keep it in is dirtier yet.

Answer (score 3):

From the new [free dictionary online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scumbag)

> scumbag [ˈskʌmˌbæg]
>   n
>   Slang an offensive or despicable person
>   [perhaps from earlier US sense: condom, from US slang scum semen + bag]

Origin:
1965–70; scum  + bag